# Delete account, bank program

Tags: java, iterator

Can you help me delete an account from my bank program?

The method for deleating a customer is working fine. A customer can have many accounts, and the code for deleting one of them is not working. What it does is that it removes the entire customer, and not only the account.
I Believe it has something to do with the iterator. My code deletes it, which is the iterator in customerlist. But how can I do it instead?

Method for deleting customer:

```
public void deleteCustomer(String customerNumber) {        
    Iterator<Customer> it = customers.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Customer c = it.next();
        if (c.getNumber().equals(customerNumber)) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Method for deleting account (non working):

```
public void deleteAccount(String accountId, String customerNumber) {        
    Iterator<Customer> it = customers.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Customer c = it.next();
        if (c.getNumber().equals(customerNumber)) {
            for(Account a: c.getAccounts()) {
                if(a.getAccountId().equals(accountId)) {
                    it.remove();                            //I Think it's wrong here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: We need to know details of that customer object - where did you get it, and what does the delete() method on it do?  How is it saved to a dataqbase?

Comment: Well yeah, you're calling `it.remove` which will remove the last element returned from the collection itself. So it removes the 'Customer' object that your operating on, when apparently you just mean to remove the account? You'd need a second iterator for your Account objects, and then call the `remove` on the correct account while iterating through the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create an `Iterator` on the accounts, and not the customers:

```
for(Customer c : customers) {
    if (c.getNumber().equals(customerNumber)) {
        Iterator<Account> it = c.getAccounts().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Account a = it.next();
            if(a.getAccountId().equals(accountId)) {
                it.remove();
                break;                            
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I also added `break` when the account and customer are found.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a second level of iteration over the accounts using the `Iterator` class, the same way you're doing to iterate over the customers. The problem in your code is with the following statement (as you have doubted):

```
it.remove();
```

`it` references an iterator for the list of *customers*. Hence what this line does is remove the customer and not the account. Simply add another loop as follows:

```
Iterator<Customer> it = customers.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Customer c = it.next();
    if (c.getNumber().equals(customerNumber)) {
        Iterator<Account> it2 = c.getAccounts().iterator();
        while (it2.hasNext()) {
           Account a = it2.next();       
           if (a.getAccountId().equals(accountId)) {
               it2.remove();                      
           }
        }
    }
}
```